# Query a table for duplicate attribute value

Tags: sql, postgresql, datatables

This is a chunk of a table that I want to query

[image]

I want to `DISTINCT` retrun all names of subjects, that are at the same time part of BSc and MSc degrees, for example if a subject is only of type BSc or MSc, it should not be returned. I need help doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "subject", you mean "name", then a simple aggregation with `having` suffices:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having count(*) filter (where degree = 'Bsc') > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where degree = 'Msc') > 0;
```

Comment: I'm unfortunately only allowed to use SELECT FROM queries (without filtering), and also I should mention that I'm using PostgreSQL. By subject I indeed mean the `name` attribute.

Comment: I am unfortunately only allowed to use hammers.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, using `in` and `having` clause.

```
select distinct name from tableA t1
where name in (select name from
        (select distinct name, pursueddegree from tableA) t1
    group by t1.name
    having count(1) > 1)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=D2ywb7eTLq).

Answer (score 0):

This would work for any RDBMS system.

```
select name from your_table
where pursueddegree in ('BSc','Msc')
group by name 
having count(distinct pursueddegree) = 2
```